# What injuries can leave permanent damage while allowing someone to move freely/fight?

Tags: biology, humans, anatomy, combat, medical

I want to have a character who used to be the captain of/personal guard for a queen but has to retire due to an injury but I can't find any injury that would leave permenant damage without leaving them completly unable to fight.

I don't want to go as far as loosing a limb but are there any other injuries that could occur while fighting that might leave someone with chronic pain or that would stop them from being able to keep their job as guard while still allowing them to fight occasionally?

(to be clear this is set in a historical fantasy setting without firearms)

edit: ok so apparently this is too much about character building rather than worldbuilding so I shouldnt have posted it here but I also can't delete since it's been answered already so idrk what to do

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a worldbuilding question but a research question related to events that take place within an already built world.

Comment: @sphennings we've answered questions like this before: in fact, most "what kind of poison will do X?" questions fall into this category. It's asking how the "creature" works, in this case humans. I believe if falls into the finite list of things category - but that's always been muddy water.

Comment: @JBH the question is asking for information to build a character not a world. We don’t answer questions that aren’t about worldbuilding, regardless of their other attributes.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research - searching for "causes of military medical discharges" gives a plethora of results for not only the injuries but the statistical distribution of who tends to suffer from them based on age, fitness, BMI, height, weight, marital status (!) and a bunch of other factors.  Most of it is, naturally, for modern armies, but the type of injuries people suffer in peacetime armies are rarely gunshots anyway.

Comment: @sphennings aka [tag:creature-design]. I will grant that it's a good example of what I consider the failure of the [Real World Question policy](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6161/40609), which I'd love to see changed.

Comment: @JBH But OP isn’t asking about a creature. They’re asking about a singular specific character. As written there isn’t a worldbuilding problem to be solved. Questions need to actually be about building a fictional world, not just have the potential to be used to build one.

Comment: @sphennings I'm sorry, I just don't see it that way. The question isn't asking about something that can only happen to one character. The OP is asking about the traits of the people of his world that can be advantageous to a story problem. The whole point of worldbuilding is to create the infrastructure needed to tell a story. Asking which solution is "best" would be too story-based. Asking what weaknesses exist, IMO, isn't. It's just [tag:creature-design].

Comment: "I want to have a character who..." is literally how the question starts. The world will be exactly the same regardless of what injury this character has. There are ways to ask about injuries on this site but they need to be asked within the context of building a fictional world not building a character.

Answer (score 8):

**CTE**

Concussions, head injuries, KOs etc. etc.

There are a legion of High level athletes who are still absolute **Monsters** in hand-to-hand fighting, who are clearly cognitively impaired *to the point where a monarch may not want to have them in their royal guard*.

Chris Benoit (Wrestler, well documented case of CTE, murdered wife and kids) was Wrestling right up to the point he did what he did. Yes Wrestling is Sports Entertainment and not actual combat - in terms of physical exertion, pain taken (Jumping from the top rope is still going to hurt) and limb control, it is up there.

**Any Joint or Pain or ache injury**

That is one of the funning things about Adrenalin and Muscle Memory - you can see someone hobbling around, clearly mobility impaired - put them in the ring and suddenly they can still duck and weave. There is a great video of Cus D'Amato sparring with Muhammed Ali and showing him some old-man moves.[Here](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/d1nEBbTZkT4) - There are countless examples of Military guys (in their 30s and 40s) who are in pain moving around, but once stuff starts happening, they start moving.

Imagine for a moment a monarch sees one of their Royal guard shuffling around on a cold winter morning and thinks 'Nah, they can't protect me anymore'

Answer (score 5):

1. **Losing an eye**: no depth perception.
2. **Lost hearing** (at least in one ear): can fight only what one sees or cannot triangulate sound. There's a lot you can do with hearing. An injury causing tinnitus (ringing in the ears, loud and distracting, if you've not known someone with the condition... believe me). Broken ear drums (loss of critical balance). Compromised sinuses... all kinds of things.
3. **Joint damage**: limited mobility or limited endurance.
4. **Acute muscle damage** (aka, a good chunk went missing): can still move, but it hurts like the devil.
5. **Nerve damage**: There's a lot you can do with this, too. Chronic pain. Can't feel the sword you're gripping. The pain you feel actually belongs somewhere else. *That's something I experienced: knee damage meant when I scratched the right side of the knee cap I could feel it on the left side. It took almost a year for the brain to re-interpret the signals and get it all sorted out.*
6. Finally, **3rd degree burns** somewhere important, like the hand or at a joint, such that the burn scars are whomping hard to work with (and you can add nerve damage if you want chronic pain).

Answer (score 3):

His job requires an elite athlete. Elite athletes retire due to injuries all the time - fortunately very few are amputations!

According to the [British journal of sports medicine](https://bjsm.bmj.com/content/55/Suppl_1/A72.3) discussing the retirement due to injuries of Olympic athletes:

> The main locations of injuries that were reported to be responsible
> for retirement from sport were the lower back (25.8%), knee (25.0%),
> lower leg (8.3%), ankle (7.6%), Achilles tendon (6.8%), shoulder
> (6.8%), hip (5.3%), and thigh (5.3%). The main types of injury
> reported to be responsible for early retirement from sport were soft
> tissue related (23.9%), injuries to the intervertebral disc (19.0%),
> intervertebral joint (18.2%), and cartilage injuries at the hip and
> knee (9.1%).

If you want a retired badass who can't make any kind of career involving professional violence, is still young*, and can still come out of retirement to lay waste the kingdom's enemies, I'd suggest having him suffer a traumatic brain injury. He recovers, but the doctor tells him that any future hard blow to the head could kill him on the spot, helmet or no helmet.

*"being over 45" is also a good reason to retire from a career as an elite combat athlete.